# Send emails via Mandrill within Lumen Framework

Tags: laravel, lumen, mandrill

I already created file in config directory **services.php** with this code:

```
<?php
     return [
       'mandrill' => [
            'secret' => env('MANDRILL_SECRET'),
        ],
     ],
];
```

Also, dependency **illuminate/mail** (v.^6.3) was added to the project.

But, when I try to send email with this line of code

```
Mail::to($user->email)->send(new Welcome($user));
```

I see an error: `{"data":null,"errors":{"messages":"Driver [mandrill] not supported.","fields":[]}}`

Framework version - Lumen (6.0.2) (Laravel Components ^6.0)

Comment: support for mandrill was dropped in 5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for Mandrill mail service was dropped by [this commit](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/e2461f19c3b951f7cbb4b424601cad1f6553774a)

```
Remove Mandrill and SparkPost mail drivers

We're removing these drivers because we feel that general interest in these is 
declining and these aren't used by any of Laravel's core services themselves. 
We're encouraging the community to release packages for these if there's any 
interest in continued use of them.
```

So you would have to install a third party package to support it again like [intonate/laravel-mandrill-driver](https://github.com/intonate/laravel-mandrill-driver)

Also note that it was removed from [the docs in 5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/mail) so you have to read the [5.2 docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail) for official info or the above [package readme](https://github.com/intonate/laravel-mandrill-driver/blob/master/README.md)

Hope this helps